# Collarable and tame open manifolds

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be an open manifold (which means non compact and without boundary), and let us assume that $M$ is $1$-ended, i.e. it has only one topological end. $M$ is said to be *collarable* if there exists a collar neighborhood of infinity, i.e. a neighborhood of infinity which is of the form $N \simeq \partial N \times [0, + \infty)$. There is a famous theorem due to Siebenmann which gives necessary and sufficient conditions in order for an open manifold to be collarable. Now, it seems to me that this condition is equivalent to the fact that the manifold is *tame*, i.e. it is homeomorphic to $M' - \partial M'$, where $M'$ is a compact manifold with boundary. In fact, our $M'$ is given by the union of the "compactification" of the collar neighborhood and its complementary. Am I missing something? For more precise definitions I leave here the following link https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.6741.pdf .

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. For one, although you mention Siebenmann's condition, you seem to be only mentioning it in passing, and it does not seem to be pertinent to your question. Is that correct?

Comment: @LeeMosher I am asking if a tame manifold is the same as a collarable manifold, for the reasons I have written in the question. I mentioned Siebenmann's condition in order to give the reader a little bit of context; maybe while reading of this theorem some bells could ring in the reader's head

Comment: I think your question is probably best answered by searching the term "tame" in that paper you linked. I did that, and ran across a passage at the end of Section 3.4, starting towards the bottom of page 20. It seems that this word "tame" is not as fixed in meaning as one might hope.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, it is not so fixed in meaning; what I mean for tame is that it is homeomorphic to $M' \setminus \partial M'$ where $M'$ is a compact manifold with boundary, as I have written in the question.

Comment: Okay, in that case, the answer to your question is "no, you are not missing anything".

Comment: Okay perfect, thank you for your comments!